# RowSpan and alternate row color at the same time using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to use row span on 1 column (if the value of the next row is same)
and alternate the row color according to the above situation.

I managed to get the row span working the way i wanted but can`t alternate the rows. BatchNo: 3694217 row should be blue aswell.

Here is the current output:

[image]

Asp

```
<asp:GridView ID="visualisation" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="OnDataBound" OnItemDataBound="Item_Bound" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="15" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkOliveGreen" GridLines="Both">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchNo" HeaderText="BatchNo" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"  />                                    
                    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="DataLoaded" HeaderText="DataLoaded" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"  />
                    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Errors" HeaderText="Errors" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"  />
                    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProcessingRun" HeaderText="ProcessingRun" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"  />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataT();
            visualisation.DataBind();

        }

        public void dataT()
        {
            DataTable dtVisu = new DataTable();

            dtVisu.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BatchNo", typeof(System.String)));
            dtVisu.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(System.String)));
            dtVisu.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DataLoaded", typeof(System.String)));
            dtVisu.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Errors", typeof(System.String)));
            dtVisu.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProcessingRun", typeof(System.String)));
            //dtVisu.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("alignRow", typeof(System.String)));


            DataRow dr = dtVisu.NewRow();
            dr["BatchNo"] = "3704500";
            dr["Type"] = "Calibration";
            dr["DataLoaded"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dr["Errors"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dr["ProcessingRun"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            //dr["alignRow"] = "1";
            dtVisu.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dtVisu.NewRow();
            dr["BatchNo"] = "3704542";
            dr["Type"] = "Range Settings";
            dr["DataLoaded"] = "images/r4-12.png";
            dr["Errors"] = "images/r4-12.png";
            dr["ProcessingRun"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dtVisu.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtVisu.NewRow();
            dr["BatchNo"] = "3704542";
            dr["Type"] = "Range Settings";
            dr["DataLoaded"] = "images/r4-12.png";
            dr["Errors"] = "images/r4-12.png";
            dr["ProcessingRun"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dtVisu.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtVisu.NewRow();
            dr["BatchNo"] = "3687345";
            dr["Type"] = "Calibration";
            dr["DataLoaded"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dr["Errors"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dr["ProcessingRun"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dtVisu.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtVisu.NewRow();
            dr["BatchNo"] = "3694217";
            dr["Type"] = "Calibration";
            dr["DataLoaded"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dr["Errors"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dr["ProcessingRun"] = "images/g4-12.png";
            dtVisu.Rows.Add(dr);



            visualisation.DataSource = dtVisu;
        }

protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int RowSpan = 2;
            for (int i = visualisation.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                GridViewRow currRow = visualisation.Rows[i];
                GridViewRow prevRow = visualisation.Rows[i + 1];

                if (currRow.Cells[0].Text == prevRow.Cells[0].Text)
                {
                    currRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = RowSpan;
                    prevRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                    RowSpan += 1;

                    currRow.BackColor = Color.FromName("#7AA5D6");
                    prevRow.BackColor = Color.FromName("#7AA5D6");
                }
                else
                {
                    RowSpan = 2;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any code that colors any rows except the two. Also, why are you going through the rows in reverse order?

Comment: I could not get it working that is why i never included the code for color. the reason for reverse order is i wont get null value and i can compare them easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a separate counter of your rows to assign alternating colors. Note that in current code colors alternate only if rows are spanned, therefore single row is not hghlighted. Something around this should do the trick:

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int RowSpan = 2;
    // actual row counter, spanned rows count as one
    int rowCount = 0;
    for (int i = visualisation.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        GridViewRow currRow = visualisation.Rows[i];
        GridViewRow prevRow = visualisation.Rows[i + 1];

        if (currRow.Cells[0].Text == prevRow.Cells[0].Text)
        {
            currRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = RowSpan;
            prevRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            RowSpan += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            RowSpan = 2;
            //it was a new row
            rowCount++;
        }

        if (rowCount % 2 == 0)
        {
            currRow.BackColor = Color.FromName("#7AA5D6");            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i assign back color to the single row?

Comment: @ emre22 : I don't think you loop through all of the rows.

Comment: Ok. I got it working this time. I have added AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor